# Vector space and scalar field

Tags: linear-algebra

When we define the vector field $\mathbb{V}$ we always assign a field $\mathbb{F}$ to it. So the field $\mathbb{F}$ is needed because of the scalar product or we also require each component of a vector in $\mathbb{V}$ is from $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: What is the field $\mathbb F$ in this context? Is it a scalar field?

Comment: The field $\mathbb F$ is needed in the definition of the vector space $V$ because one of the axioms a vector space has to satisfy is that there is a mapping $\cdot: \mathbb F \times V \rightarrow V$ that maps a pair $(x,v)$ with $x \in \mathbb F$, $v \in V$ to a new vector $x\cdot v \in V$. For this map (which has certain properties such as $(xy)\cdot v = x \cdot (y \cdot v))$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb F$ and $v \in V$) to be defined we need to specify from which field we take the "scalars" $x$. This has nothing to do with an inner product on $V$.

Comment: @Lukas Got it. So it's valid if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ and our $\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{R}^n$ right?

Comment: @PC1 Yeah it is a scalar field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard vector space over a field $\Bbb F$ is the $n-$ dimensional $V=\Bbb F^n$.

Actually any two finite dimensional vector spaces over the same field (of the same dimension) are isomorphic. Halmos has a book on these.

So in a sense yes.

A generalization is modules over rings.

There are also infinite dimensional vector spaces. Function spaces, like $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, can provide examples of this.

In general,  there are different funky examples you can come up with.   Wait for an expert.   But you can do $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb C$, or vice versa! Or over $\Bbb Q$.

Look up quaternion vector space,  for instance.

Not to ramble,  but finite fields are an interesting application of vector spaces.   In particular,  the field of order $p^n$ is an $n-$ dimensional vector space over its "prime subfield".

I don't know anything about the $p-$ adic stuff.

Comment: I got it, thanks. So the scalar field $\mathbb{F}$ have nothing to do with the structure of $\mathbb{V}$ as long as it satisfy all those axioms of being a field right?

Comment: Well, yes.  They're sort of two separate entities.